# Is class data brought into memory every time it is accessed from a member function?

Tags: c++, caching

In the function 'doSomething' will 'number' be brought into cache every time it is incremented?

edit:
I am asking because I came across some comments by Mike Acton. He made [this](https://photos.smugmug.com/Other/2008-07-15-by-Eye-Fi/n-xmKDH/i-VtrWfrv/0/fd5f564f/X2/i-VtrWfrv-X2.jpg) comment and then suggested using a local register. [Here](https://macton.smugmug.com/Other/2008-07-15-by-Eye-Fi/n-xmKDH/i-BrHWXdJ) is the entire collection of comments.

```
    class a
    {
    public:
        int number;
        void doSomething();
    }

    void a::doSomething()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
        {
            number += i;
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        a;
        a.doSomething();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I'd say that it'll *stay* in cache... That's what caches are for: keeping data that keeps being accessed in fast memory near the processor.

Comment: As far as you are concerned it already is in memory. The *operating system* will page it in and out based on usage. It doesn't have anything to do with the compiler or the language.

Comment: And I certainly don't propose to obtain and wade through 57 pages of a document with such a title, but Mike Acton, whoever he may be, has merely asked a stupid question. There is nothing wrong with writing to a class member in an inner loop. *If and only if* it has been established that this is a performance bottleneck, you might consider using a register, but you would then have to worry about semantic correctness if other threads were involved. The general principle is to write straightforward code and let the compiler worry about performance, until shown otherwise.

Comment: @EJP - yes and ... I read about half that deck and decided Mike Acton, whoever he is, isn't the code review god he thinks he is.  Some suggestions are good (though obvious) ... others not so hot.  OP should think things through, running micro-experiments and looking at generated code, if necessary

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about slide 45, but I will comment on *all* these slides.

- Slide 7: there is no float-to-int conversion here. There is an int-to-float conversion.
- Slide 11: there are no 'crazy branches' here. I would certainly omit the `else`s on the grounds of source code redundancy, but no decent compiler would generate branches for them anyway. Even if it did, they are never taken, so they only cost space, not time.
- Slides 12-16 and 17-20 and 21-23 are single complaints, not five/four/three respectively, about the semantics of the application, not general principles.
- Slides 24-28 state the inane opinion that '"good" use[s]' of `virtual` are 'hard to come by'.
- Slide 29 is another inane rant. There is nothing wrong with using names for manifest constants, *especially* physical constants of the universe or mathematical constants. See PI for a common example.
- Slide 31 flatly contradicts slides 12 to 23 inclusive.
- Slide 32 is a probably pointless micro-optimization. `m` is an induction variable, so there is a strong possibility it is already optimized away by the compiler.
- Slide 35 appears to also contradict slides 12 to 23 inclusive.
- Slide 45: there is nothing wrong with writing to a class member in an inner loop, and the implied recommendation to use a register or local variable, whatever is intended here, has space costs and semantic risks.
- Slide 46: the `register` declaration has been ignored by C and C++ compilers for several decades. The compiler is perfectly capable of making this optimization for itself, given enough information about semantic constraints.
- Slides 47-50: incomprehensible.
- Slide 51: possible semantic change, not addressed.
- Slides 53-4: Oh, this comment is not useful. An `enum` value doesn't inherently 'forc[e] unneeded branches'. A proper explanation is required and not provided.
- Slide 55: references are not 'pointless cruft', and neither is returning one.
- Slide 56: incomprehensible.
- Slide 57: unprofessional and offensive.

I don't think I've read such rubbish for over 20 years. I would have to seriously question the mentality of someone who used four and five post-it notes per issue. And he rarely if ever provides an actual solution.

Comment: Mike Acton's a prolific figure in the AAA game developer community in particular, he's currently on of the heads at Unity DOTs. Before that he was the Engine Director at Insomniac Games. I definitely wouldn't right him off, he has very real experience. Although he can have a rather antagonistic style :)

Comment: Maybe he is good in some other language, but he has little understanding of C++ internals, and, worse, thinks he does. Premature optimization is the root of all evil, as a much, much better coder one said.

Comment: He's working in the context of high performance game engines. Proverbs like "premature optimization is the root of all evil" are not appropriate in that context, one of the primary criteria for judging the value of an engine programmer is performance. Why are you saying he doesn't understand C++ compiler internals? Again, he's literally shipped AAA, open world titles on consoles, and leads DOTS at Unity --> whose core technology is a special compiler (BURST) which optimizes and SIMID-ifies a subset of C# code... It's amazing how polemical these answers/comments are.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably, if the loop is actually emitted, it'll be brought in cache on the first access, and stay there until the end of the loop (again, probably - it's not like the compiler has particular control over this, caches are generally transparently introduced over plain memory accesses).

Notice that the compiler here is also allowed to transform the code to something like:

```
int n = number;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    n += i;
}
number = n;
```

As there are no function calls in the loop that may see the intermediate state of `number` (nor memory barriers that force the intermediate state to be visible to other threads). `n` here will probably be a register, so cache is not relevant.

Finally, several modern compilers will actually optimize it to:

```
number += 1225;
```

So there aren't so many cache accesses to get worried about.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I suspected that would be the case but, is it guaranteed that the compiler will do this? I just added an edit to hopefully give some more context to my question.

Comment: Keeping in cache, as I said, is the processor's job, the compiler can do nothing about that. For the other optimizations, as always there's no strict guarantee. In a trivial case such as this it's pretty much sure that some level of optimization will be applied; in more complicated cases (for example where memory barriers or calls to other functions are present) the compiler may either not be authorized to hoist the load/store (because it potentially changes the semantics) or may not be smart enough to see that it would be harmless. In these cases, you may perform the optimization yourself.

Comment: Still, in general keeping modifications on local variables when possible is not bad advice; besides letting stuff be placed in registers, in general helps the optimizer by narrowing the scope of its thoughts.